# Why python+sqlite3 is extremely slow?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlite

I tried to process the same request to the same database using "Python 2.7.4 + sqlite3" and "Firefox SQLite Manager 0.8.0".

On the tiny database (8000 records) both Python and Firefox work fast and give the same result.

On the bigger database (2600000 records):

- SQLite Manager processed database in 28seconds (24 records)
- Python program is working already for 20 minutes without any result

What can be wrong with the following program, so python sqlite3 cannot process the query in reasonable time, while the same request can be processed faster?

```
import sqlite3

_sql1 = """SELECT DISTINCT J2.rule_description,
                J2.feature_type,
                J2.action_item_id,
                J2.rule_items
FROM journal J1,
     journal J2
WHERE J1.base = J2.base
    AND J1.action_item_id=J2.action_item_id
    AND J1.type="Action disabled"
    AND J2.type="Action applied"
    AND J1.rule_description="Some test rule"
    AND J1.action_item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 30, 31, 32)
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sqlite_output = r'D:\results.sqlite'
    with sqlite3.connect(sqlite_output) as connection:
        for row in connection.execute(_sql1):
            print row
```

**UPDATE:** [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) also returns the same 24 records

**UPDATE2:** sqlite3.sqlite_version is '3.6.21'

Comment: Are you certain that SQLite Manager is processing **all** result rows? Your Python program is...

Comment: Yes, "Command Line Shell For SQLite" also gives the same 24 records

Comment: Maybe the database file is locked by SQLite Manager?

Comment: Check the SQLite version (`SELECT sqlite_version();`).

Comment: Database is not locked: the same after reboot

Comment: @CL version is 3.6.21

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems, that the problem is related with the old version of sqlite that shipped with Python 2.7. Everything works fine in python 3.3.

Thanks a lot to @CL for the great comment!

In python 2.7

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.6.21'
```

In python 3.3

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.12'
```

Comment: You can keep using Python 2.7 by upgrading sqlite, if needed.

Comment: @EOL Another (maybe better) solution is to create indices. I was just curious about the difference in the performance

Comment: Yeah, indexes can give a big speed up. I was curious too, so +1 to the question and to your answer from me. :)

Comment: An update operation that was a dog (300 seconds for 50,000 records) went to 2 seconds after upgrading from python 2.7 from sqlite3 version '3.6.21' to '3.8.7.4'.
Upgrade instructions were here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8761073/1804262

Comment: I just experienced a similar speed up by upgrading the dll file.  I was running into exactly the same problem - queries running quickly through sqlite command line, but really slowly in Python.  it was the 3.6.21 dll which was the problem for me too.