# Installing pysqlite in python with sqlite 3 version with custom file header 

Tags: python, pysqlite

I wan to compile sqlite with custom file header 
I followed the step given here http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite

```
Download pysqlite 
Extract it 
export  CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_FILE_HEADER=\\\"vivek\\\"" 
Run  python   setup.py build_static 
python   setup.py install  -f
```

But when run python and check sqlite version

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

It is giving old version of sqlite. I think it should be 3. 
I tried opening the database but I am getting error

```
 sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database


Python Version

python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

Comment: It's not so helpful to change your question this much; answerers do not get notified of the changes. Better use a new post next time to ask a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upgrade the sqlite3 package in Python 2.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333095/how-can-i-upgrade-the-sqlite3-package-in-python-2-6)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok I will close this question and start another one. First I thought it sqlite version problem but as you told that is module version not sqlite. Then I checked for other problems.

Comment: No need to close it now; I've already altered my answer too. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [force python to forego native sqlite3 and use the (installed) latest sqlite3 version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1545479)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of the PySqlite page on the Trac site:

> If you're using Python 2.5 and up, you already have a working version of pysqlite 2, bundled as sqlite3. You can stop here ;-)

You are using python 2.7, so there is *no* need to install a custom version. pysqlite comes bundled with your python version already.

`pysqlite` is the "glue" that makes sqlite available to python. Your system sqlite itself needs to be upgraded, not the glue library.

See [How can I upgrade the sqlite3 package in Python 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333095/how-can-i-upgrade-the-sqlite3-package-in-python-2-6)

Comment: I am getting error sqlite3.DatabaseError:  file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: That's a different problem then; what python version are you on in any case?

Comment: one more thing I am compiling sqlite with custom file header. 
python version 2.7.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver
This is more better answer.

Comment: Glad you found something that helped! You didn't specify what platform you were on so I picked one for you before.