# Pandas read_sql() of a view keeps double quotes in columns with spaces

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have an sqlite database with a view of several tables with a lot of columns with spaces in their names (I know, I know, not good practice, but it's out of my control).

Anyways, so the problem that I'm having is related to the spaces in the column names when using `pd.read_sql('SELECT "stupid column with space" from StupidView',con=db)`.  **It keeps keeping the quotes in the column name when querying the view but not when querying the table itself!** Same SQL on the table returns columns without being wrapped in quotes.  Am I missing something here?  Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Working standalone example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

# Create the database
db = sqlite3.connect("Sample Database.sqlite")
cursor = db.cursor()

# Create a table
df = pd.DataFrame({"Stupid column with space":[1,2,3,4],
                    "MrNoSpace":[1,2,3,4]})

# Push the tables to the database
df.to_sql(name="StupidTable", con=db, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Just in case you're running this more than once, drop the view if it exists
try: cursor.execute("DROP VIEW StupidView;")
except: pass

# Execute the sql that creates the view
cursor.execute("""
CREATE VIEW StupidView AS
SELECT StupidTable.*
FROM  StupidTable""")
db.commit()

# Execute the SQL and print the results
Test1_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT "Stupid column with space", "MrNoSpace" FROM StupidView',con=db)     # read data from the view
Test2_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT "Stupid column with space", "MrNoSpace" FROM Table1',con=db)         # same sql but on the table
Test3_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT `Stupid column with space`, `MrNoSpace` FROM StupidView',con=db)     # using ` and not "
Test4_df = pd.read_sql('SELECT  [Stupid column with space],   [MrNoSpace]  FROM StupidView',con=db) # using []

print Test1_df
print Test2_df
print Test3_df
print Test4_df
```

**Output:**

*Test1_df - Query on the view: columns are wrapped in double quotes*

```
   "Stupid column with space"  "MrNoSpace"
0                           1            1
1                           2            2
2                           3            3
3                           4            4
```

*Test2_df - Same query but on the table: now with no quotes in column names*

```
   Stupid column with space  MrNoSpace
0                         1          1
1                         2          2
2                         3          3
3                         4          4
```

*Test3_df - Keeps the column names wrapped in ` (works fine if the query on a table but not a view)*

```
   `Stupid column with space`  `MrNoSpace`
0                           1            1
1                           2            2
2                           3            3
3                           4            4
```

*Test4_df - Drops the column names altogether (works fine if used on table not view)*

```
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
```

Comment: It works consistently for me (Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7 64-bit) - for all 4 variant no quotes (like in your `Test2_df` case)

Comment: Interesting... I'm on Python 2.7.11 (Pandas 0.18.0). Sounds like a python issue.

Comment: I just tested it on Python 2.7.11 and i had the same issue as you

Comment: So it looks like its an sqlite problem: `print cursor.execute('SELECT "Stupid column with space", "MrNoSpace" FROM StupidView').description` and `print cursor.execute('SELECT "Stupid column with space", "MrNoSpace" FROM Table1').description`

Comment: I would say it's a problem with Python 2.7's implementation of sqlite

Comment: Yea actually just found the bug (closed with no fix): http://bugs.python.org/issue19167

Comment: you are right: my Python 2.7.11's `sqlite3` module uses `sqlite3.sqlite_version`: 3.6.21 and Python 3.5.1 `sqlite3.sqlite_version`: 3.8.11

Comment: Try giving the view a different column alias and see if import still has issue: `CREATE VIEW StupidView AS SELECT StupidTable."Stupid column with space" As "Another stupid column with space" FROM  StupidTable`

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an issue with the version of sqlite that python 2.7 uses that will not be officially fixed (http://bugs.python.org/issue19167).

If you want to still use python  2.7 or below, you can replace the `sqlite.dll` in `C:\Python27\DLLs` a newer version downloaded from here: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.  Views now work as expected with python 2.7 as far as I can tell.

With help from the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3341117/1754273